# SharePoint responsive design

Tags: responsive

I am hunting for some help to do sharepoint site responsive. I just started to look into css media queries but it did not work. Any thoughts on this.? I am adding simple

```
<style>
#customDiv {background-color: lightgreen;}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
#customDiv{
background-color: lightblue;
}
}
</style>​​

<div id="customDiv">
```

​​​​

Resize the browserwindow. When the width of this document is less than 300 pixels, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "lightgreen".

any inputs will be better as I am new to this responsive design.

Comment: which Responsive Framework you are using?

Comment: no..at this moment I am not using any framework just trying to avoid that. just using media queries.! But doesnt work..it works in fiddle..

Comment: I believe just adding a media query alone won't make it responsive (atleast in SharePoint world)

Comment: yeah..it looks like this..! any suggestions on frameworks or any other way to make it responsive will be helpful ..:)

Answer (score 0):

Branding SharePoint can be a fun, rewarding yet often times challenging endeavor. SharePoint is extremely powerful, but with that power comes complexity that makes its way into the front end HTML, JavaScript and CSS as well. You throw Responsive Web Design principles and a grid layout, which is all of the rage right now in web design, and you might be in for it.

For SharePoint one is readily available http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/